# Is there another way to do a WHERE <> 0 filter to many columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, where-clause

This is my query:

```
SELECT [id],[reasoncode], 
[jan], [feb],[mar],[apr],[may,[jun],
[jul],[aug],[sep],[oct],[nov],[dec] from table
```

Now what I want to know is if there is another way to filter away 0 using WHERE than this??

```
SELECT [id],[reasoncode], 
[jan], [feb],[mar],[apr],[may,[jun],
[jul],[aug],[sep],[oct],[nov],[dec] from table
WHERE 
[jan] <> 0 and   
[feb] <> 0 and
[mar] <> 0 and
[apr] <> 0 and
[may] <> 0 and
[jun] <> 0 and
[jul] <> 0 and
[aug] <> 0 and
[sep] <> 0 and
[oct] <> 0 and
[nov] <> 0 and
[dec] <> 0
from table
```

Suggestions?

------Update

I only want to exclude the row if all the rows have zero.
This is the data I have to work with, so there is not a "month" column available.

Comment: erm wtf?!?........That doesn't look a very good schema design...

Comment: I think without refactoring DB Schema there is no other way

Comment: Well, you can use the fact that a * b * c = 0 if and only if any of a, b, c is equal to 0. But yeah, design of this table is deeply flawed: what's not stored in `jan`-`dec` columns is probably better done in `month` column.

Comment: What is the range of data in the month columns, is it 0/1 or can it be any number?

Comment: So if any zeros appear in a row, you want that row to be excluded?

Comment: I only want to exclude the row if all the rows have zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to exclude where all the (month) columns are 0 then add all of the month columns together and test like so

```
Where jan+feb+mar+apr+may+jun+jul+aug+sep+oct+nov+dec<>0
```

This assumes that your valid values for each of the month columns are 0 or positive, and that the columns are int columns not bit columns.  If negative values are allowed for each month, then you could use

```
Where abs(jan) + ... + abs(dec) <> 0
```

and if you are using bit columns then

```
Where convert(int,jan) + ... + convert(int,dec) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure what your goal is, but...

if your goal is to make less comparisons and/or shorter SQL, you can check the result of multiplication, like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE jan * feb * mar * apr * (... and so on) <> 0
```

This way if one of the columns is `0`, the expression is `0` too, and the condition is not met. But I'm not saying this is better / faster / cleaner. It's just a trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a newer version of MYSQL, you could try the LEAST operator, and check that none of the values are 0. Something like:

```
SELECT [id],[reasoncode],  [jan], [feb],[mar],[apr],[may,[jun],
[jul],[aug],[sep],[oct],[nov],[dec] 
from table 
WHERE  
LEAST([jan],[feb],[mar],[apr],[may],[jun],[jul],[aug],[sep],[oct],[nov],[dec]) <> 0
```

Comment: This will not work as required if the column values may be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT id,reasoncode, 
       jan, feb,mar,apr,may,jun,
       jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec
FROM table
WHERE
  jan*feb*mar*apr*may*jun*jul*aug*sep*oct*nov*dec<>0
```